# iTunes keeps saying there is not enough room when transferring music

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, music-management

I dragged a folder containing lots of music into my iPod touch in iTunes. A message pops up saying there isn't enough room and it will try to transfer as many songs as possible. I click the button to dismiss the message, and then it will start transferring songs. After transferring a few songs the message pops up again. This keeps on repeating. I should only have to see this message once, right? Why does it keep coming up? What is the solution?

Comment: How much free space is remaining on your iPod touch and how large is the folder you dragged into iTunes?

Comment: The folder is larger than the remaining space of course.

Comment: I have a feeling this message pops up for each song that is over the limit, which means you'll have to grin and bear it.

Comment: No it pops up whenever it goes into a new directory. The folder I'm trying to move has subfolders inside. When I click ok it transfers all the files from  a subfolder, then when it goes to the next subfolder it repeats the message.